# Changing service account for workflow manager

Tags: workflow-manager

I need to change the service account for workflow manager. Preferably, I'd like to avoid [uninstalling and reinstalling workflow manager](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27689.sharepoint-2013-how-to-fully-uninstall-workflow-manager-1-0.aspx) to do so. The configuration is correct, however the RunAs account is not.

It seems like this should be possible after [reading this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/55157e0e-d827-4fc9-b0dc-d45b78fcf649/changing-the-runas-account-without-reinstalling-workflow-manger?forum=wflmgr) and using the below powershell:

```
Stop-SBFarm
Set-SBFarm -RunAsAccount Domain\Username
$RunAsPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force '<password>'
[RunOnAllNodes] Update-SBHost -RunAsPassword $RunAsPassword

Start-SBFarm
```

However, if I try to use the Set-SBFarm or Update-SBHost cmdlets I get an error:

```
The term 'Set-SBFarm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file or operable program.
```

Does anybody know what I'm missing when trying to run the powershell script above? If the correct approach is really to uninstall and reinstall workflow manager, could someone provide an explanation for why that's necessary over just changing the service account?

Edit: I believe that a cumulative update or service bus 1.1 and/or workflow manager 1.1 may be required here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run these commands in the workflow manager powershell console not SharePoint power shell console.

On the Workflow manager server: `Start > All Program > Workflow Manager > Worfklow Manager PowerShell` from here run as administrator.

I did the testing on my laptop when i Install the Service Bus 1.1 after i am able to run the Set-SBfarm command.[image]

But with Service Bus 1.0(as a part of the Workflow Manager 1.0) i am getting the same error.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was running these in the Workflow Manager PowerShell console. I still receive the not recognized error in the Workflow Manager Powershell console.

Comment: are you running a script file or line by line....sometime copy paste cause some weired error, try to type the whole command...just set-sbfarm

Comment: did you stop the farm first? stop-sbfarm?

Comment: if I type each command seperatly stop-sbfarm runs and I can see everything is stopped. once I try to run set-sbfarm I get the same error.
start-sbfarm will also start the service again.

Comment: any chance you're running cu1 or cu2 for workflow manager? or workflow manager 1.1? I'm wondering if the set-sbfarm cmdlet is part of one of those updates?

Comment: i think this command introduced in the service bus 1.1 and will be part of the latest cu or may need to install the service bus 1.1.

Comment: see updated answer.

Comment: I'm going to try the upgrade in our dev environment. The question I have: in [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441403.aspx) it mentions that Service Bus 1.1 does not support upgrading farms using Workflow Manager 1.0. Does this mean I cannot use this upgrade since I need Workflow Manager 1.0 or will Workflow Manager 1.0 work with Service Bus 1.1?

Comment: It appears that [Workflow Manager 1.0 CU2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42036) adds support for Service Bus 1.1. I will update this post after I have tried applying these updates.

Comment: Thanks Waqas, I'm marking this as the answer and wanted to make sure you got the bounty for confirming my suspicions. I've been able to confirm that installing Service Bus 1.1 gives the cmdlet, however I can't seem to rejoin my Service Bus farm after installing Service Bus 1.1 but that's another problem entirely. Thanks again!